# Is $K[a,b]=K(a,b)$ for algebraic $a, b$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Consider a field extension $L/K$ and $a,b \in L$ algebraic over $K$. Is it true that in this setting $K[a,b]$ is already a field?

I know that $K[a]=K(a)$ if and only if $a$ is algebraic over $K$.

Comment: Hint : $K[a,b] = K[a][b] = K(a)[b] = L[b] = L(b) = K(a,b)$ with $L=K(a)$.

Comment: Ah yes, of course $b$ is algebraic over $K(a)$ since it is algebraic over $K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, here is a hint: $$K[a,b]=K[a][b]=K(a)[b]=L'[b]=L'(b)=K(a)(b)=K(a,b)$$ with $L'=K(a)$. I used the fact that $F[y]=F(y)$ where $F$ is a field and $y$ is algebraic over $F$.

You are right: $b$ is algebraic over $K$, so in particular it is algebraic over $L$.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to show that any nonzero element of $K[a,b]$ has a reciprocal in $K[a,b]$.  But any nonzero element $u$ of $K[a,b]$ is algebraic over $K$, so $1/u$ is a polynomial in $u$.